# Blank URL pattern in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've inherited a Django app and have noticed `urlpatterns += patterns('')` and equivalent throughout `urls.py`.

e.g.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '', 
    url(r'^index.html', render_index),
)

#... 

urlpatterns += patterns(
    '', 
    url(r'^page.html', another_controller),
)
```

What is this doing? Anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's needed in the `patterns()` function because the first argument to patterns() is used as a common view prefix to your urls. From the docs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)
```

Is written more simply as:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'year_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'month_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'article_detail'),
)
```

However, since Django 1.8, the `urlpatterns` variable in `urls.py` is created with a simple list:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^index.html', render_index),
    url(r'^page.html', another_controller),
]
```

and this view prefix argument isn't needed.